# What is the difference between the unsubscribe() method in Subject and Subscription class?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I subscribed to a `Subject` using the `subscribe()` method on the `Subject` class. To unsubscribe I see two options, since the `unsubscribe()` method is available on both `Subject` and `Subscription` classes.

1. use the `Subscription` which is returned by `subject.subscribe()` method

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.subject.subscribe(next => nextHandler(), err => errHandler()); 
}

ngDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

2. Call `unsubscribe()` method directly on the subject like `subject.unsubscribe()`

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.subject.subscribe(next => nextHandler(), err => errHandler()); 
}

ngDestroy() {
  this.subject.unsubscribe();
}
```

What is the correct way of unsubscribing.

Answer (score 3):

The only difference I'm aware of is that when using `Subject.unsubscribe()` it won't trigger any dispose handlers created by piping operators.

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'; 
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

const subject = new Subject();

const subscription = subject
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => console.log('done')),
  )
  .subscribe();

subject.unsubscribe();
// subscription.unsubscribe();
```

This will never print `done` to the console because `Subject.unsubscribe()` only removes all observers. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts#L105

While using `subscription.unsubscribe()` will trigger `finalize`'s dispose handler which is probably the more predictable behavior.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-z5fjh1

Answer (score 2):

Assume Subject as a News Paper which will send you a stream of events every day and subscription is related to users subscription.

`Subject.unsubscribe()`
When you do this, you actually want to destroy the newspaper itself, you should not be doing that.
`Subscription.unsubscribe()`
When you do this, you are just unsubscribing the subscription to which you have subscribed. not the source(Subject).

See the demo below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-umf1tv